# Performance and lightness of an application: import the whole library or just the necessary modules?

Tags: python

I've been asking myself questions for some time now. If I have to distribute an application that uses large libraries, or frameworks, can I afford to import the entire library or framework, and call the modules when I need them, for example:

```
import os
import nltk
import codecs
import json
import collections
import flask

#e.g.
json.load(json_data)
collection.Counter(aList)
nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
codecs.open(aFile)
os.listdir(aPath)
```

or otherwise it is better to import only the necessary modules, in order to promote lightness and performance, for example:

```
from collections import Counter
from flask import request, Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from nltk.data import load
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords.words as stopW
from os import listdir
```

It makes me very curious to know which is the best solution when we aim to distribute an application on any platform (whether desktop, mobile, or web based).
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Performance-wise, using `import x` versus `from x import y` doesn't matter; in both cases, the entire module `x` needs to be imported. The only difference is whether symbols from the module are made available in your module's scope. It _could_ make a difference to import only e.g. `nltk.data` and not all of `nltk`, but this also depends on how that individual package is set up (i.e. it might still end up loading all its modules).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Thomas. Yes, I think most of the doubts are on nltk. For now I used `nltk.corpus.stopwords.words()`, `nltk.data.load()`, `nltk.word_tokenize()` and maybe I will use `nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First wonder

It depends what you want to achieve. Take an example: If you have a big pile of code like 500 lines it's easier for readability if you import "module" for instance

```
import myscript
```

and 400 lines later when you need to use the function from **myscript** you need to write

```
myscript.somefunction()
```

now it's easier to read your code because you already know from where is this function come from.

Because in the second scenario if you import

```
from myscript import somefunction
```

you would write

```
somefunction()
```

Which is harder to diagnose from where this function came from if you have 5 and more imports like that

But it depends on you which style to choose

Another discuss about [first wonder](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3svsu8/import_module_vs_from_module_import_function/)

## Second wonder

In your example you show something like

```
from flask import request, Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
```

and I would stick with that because of one big advantage, if you import the whole module like that

```
import flask
```

you could forget or by accident create function that already exists in the flask for instance:

```
def request():
    pass
```

and this would overwrite your imported function and give you a nice headache because now this function returns nothing.

## Performance

In both situation as [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14637/thomas) said entire module needs to be imported so in both situations performance should be the same.

## Summary

For libraries, I would choose to **from module import function** most of the times. Except for some libraries like numpy because I never saw this library imports in a different way than:

```
import numpy as np
```

And it's really convenient because it's easier to read your code for somebody else and vice versa.

But if I import many own scripts I would choose to

```
import myscript
```

because it's easier to understand from where this function comes from and function can have the same name in different scripts. But as I said it's my opinion and I think it's quite a convenient way. But if you would like to do it differently go ahead :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. At this point I think that for the most inflated libraries (e.g. os, json, and codecs) I will not import specific modules. But I still have doubts about what import from nltk. I am currently using `nltk.corpus.stopwords.words()` `nltk.data.load()` `nltk.word_tokenize()` and maybe I will use `nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer()`. I don't think that selecting the modules changes something.

Comment: If I were you I would choose to import specific modules just to get a better understanding of what I'm using. Importing specific modules like `from nltk.corpus import stopwords` for `stopwords.words()` in the sake of clarity of importing modules and easier debugging.